# Zipped File in Azure Data factory Pipeline adds extra files

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I have a Data Factory pipeline (copy activity) that zips an entire folder and adds it to an Archive Folder.
The folder Structure in Blob storage
Main/Network/data.csv.

- The source and sink use binary datasets
- source location: wildcard path ->container/Main*
- sink location:container/Archive/
- compresessiontype ->.zipdeflate

I zip the entire Main folder and copy it to another Archive folder

- Archive Folder: Main.zip

When I download this file and unzip it, the Main folder it contains
[image]

Is there a way the network file can be avoided in the pipeline?
because when I unzip the file, the network folder gets deleted since it has the same file and folder name

Thank you

Thank you

Comment: As I understand, Source is `Main/Network/data.csv` and  sink is container/Archive/main.zip, when unzip the main.zip, there is an extra file 'network', am I right?

Comment: @LeonYue that is right !.

Comment: Is the folder Archive already exist or manually create it in sink?

Comment: @LeonYue   its already available .I have tried creating it manually as well . The issue is still the same

Comment: Hello @Rachael DSouza, I tested and everything works well, there isn't a extra file 'network'. I also checked with hidden items in File View. Please check if  there are any differences between us.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried the same option and there isn't an extra same file. Please ref my steps:

**Source dataset:**

[image]
[image]

**Source settings:**
[image]

**Sink dataset:**
[image]

**Sink settings:**
[image]

**Output:**

[image]

I download it and everything is ok:
[image]

Comment: That worked!! Thank you so much .. I switched from using a wildcard to a file path in the dataset . That kinda did the trick for me.